# Attempt to de-reference a null object Salesforce Visual Force Page

Tags: php, salesforce, visualforce

I have a PHP site that calls a REST end point on Salesforce via a visualforce page.  When trying to validate the JSON response I confirmed all required fields but am now getting this error:

```
{"success":false, "message":"System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

This is coming from the following Apex Class:

```
public class WebDirectController {
```

public class ApiException extends Exception {}

```
public String response {get;set;}

private static final String PRIVATE_APPLICATION_KEY = '123';

public WebDirectController(){}

public Pagereference safeAction(){

    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

    String businessUnit;

    try {

        Map<String, String> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();

        for (String key : params.keySet()){
            system.debug(key +' -> '+ params.get(key));

        }

        if (params.containsKey('Business_Unit__c') == false){
            throw new ApiException('Unauthorized!');
        }

        businessUnit = params.get('Business_Unit__c');

        if (params.containsKey('applicationKey') == false){
            throw new ApiException('Unauthorized!');
        }
        if (params.get('applicationKey') != PRIVATE_APPLICATION_KEY){
            throw new ApiException('Unauthorized!');
        }

        // throws ApiException
        validateRequiredFields(params);


        WebDirectUtility utility = new WebDirectUtility(businessUnit);

        utility.duplicateCheck(params);

        if (utility.duplicateAccountList.isEmpty() == false){

            // if last opp is needs RX attach attachments to opp and flag opportunity

            if (utility.duplicateAccountList.get(0).Opportunities.isEmpty() == false 
                && utility.duplicateAccountList.get(0).Opportunities.get(0).Status__c == 'Needs Rx' 
                && utility.hasAttachments(params) == true){

                // save attachment.

                utility.createAttachmentList(params);

                utility.addAttachmentParentId(utility.duplicateAccountList.get(0).Opportunities.get(0).Id);

                insert utility.attachmentList;

                // set status to  'Attention- Call Center'

                Opportunity opp = utility.duplicateAccountList.get(0).Opportunities.get(0);

                opp.Status__c = 'Attention- Call Center';

                update opp;

                //utility.sendEmail(params, utility.duplicateAccountList.get(0), opp);

                response = '{"success":true}';
                return null;

            }else{

                //utility.sendEmail(params, utility.duplicateAccountList.get(0));
                response = '{"success":true}';
                return null;
            }
        }

        utility.createAll(params);



        insert utility.patientAccount;

        utility.addAttachmentParentId(utility.patientAccount.Id);
        //system.debug('attachmentList -> '+ utility.attachmentList);
        insert utility.attachmentList;

        utility.addOpportunityAccountId(utility.patientAccount.Id);
        //system.debug('patientOpportunity -> '+ utility.patientOpportunity);
        insert utility.patientOpportunity;

        utility.addLineItemOpportunityId(utility.patientOpportunity.Id);
        //system.debug('lineItemList -> '+ utility.lineItemList);
        insert utility.lineItemList;


        //send success email to kelly
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Opportunity_Url__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:utility.patientOpportunity.Id];
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  mail.setSubject(businessUnit + ' Direct Success Email');
  mail.setHtmlBody('<p>'+ businessUnit +' Direct created this opportunity: <a href="'+ opp.Opportunity_Url__c +'">'+ opp.Opportunity_Url__c +'</a></p>');
  mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{'pedrick@symplmed.com', 'childs@symplmed.com'});
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] {mail});


        response = '{"success":true}';

    }catch(Exception e){

      ErrorEmail.sendEmail(e);

        system.debug(e);
        system.debug(e.getMessage());
        system.debug(e.getStackTraceString());

        response = '{"success":false, "message":"'+ e.getMessage() +'"}';

        Database.rollback(sp); 
    }
    return null;
}


public void validateRequiredFields(Map<String, String> params){

    Set<String> requiredParams = new Set<String>{'FirstName',
                                                 'LastName',
                                                 'PersonBirthdate',
                                                 'Phone',
                                                 'PersonEmail',
                                                 'BillingStreet',
                                                 'BillingCity',
                                                 'BillingState',
                                                 'BillingPostalCode'};

    for (String rp :requiredParams){
        if (params.get(rp) == '' || params.get(rp) == null){
            throw new ApiException(rp +' is required!');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Not sure what I am missing but I am going on 2 weeks of trying to figure this out.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to close the loop on this.  By adding the stack track to the debug msg I was able to locate an error in the setup that resolved the Apex class issue,  The product line item entry in the Utility class was pointing to the wrong pricebook.

Adding the Stack Trace to the debug msg was the trick.

Thank you

Comment: Mark your own answer as accepted, you'll get some reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

Login to SF as the user whose credentials you're using in the PHP application. Open the Developer Console (upper right corner, next to your username), execute the call from PHP. Ideally you'll see a debug log generated with more detailed error message, including the line number & stacktrace.

Alternatively - go to Setup -> Debug Logs and enable tracking of that integration user (this will give you files you can view & download; Developer Console has it's quirks, can be bloody slow but at least it'll parse the log for you so it's easier to read, you can set checkpoints in it...)

Hard to say what might be going wrong, you'll have more luck with stacktrace. My wild guess is that `utility.duplicateAccountList` is null and then if your code executes `null.isEmpty()` you'll obviously be slapped with an error ;)

P.S. Have you considered exposing your piece of Apex as a proper 'REST service', not a VF page?

- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_rest
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_webservices

Comment: Thank You for the input,  The user is a Site Guest user, so there is not the ability to log in as them.  I will do some research on exposing the API as REST instead of VF, but I am under the gun timing wise, As always, and this model is working for another business unit.

Comment: You'll be able to use "Setup -> Debug Logs", search there for "[site name Guest User" user record and apply the debug logging. If it's a Site then it's likely the "Profile" lacks checkboxes to access to Accounts, Opportunities (try changing the class defintion to `public without sharing WebDirectController`? It's a bit of security risk, but just to see if it changes anything. You could also capture the request sent from PHP into "requestb.in" and try writing an unit test that passes exactly same params...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback,  Because this is a visual force page nothing is logged in the debug log in SF, I tried that.  I was able to increase logging on the PHP page pointed to the error.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense Kelly, if there's an Apex controller (or controller extension) behind the VF page it should be "loggable". You're sure you can't find "[Site's name] Guest User" available in the lookup in Setup -> Debug logs? Anyway - glad you've solved it :)

Comment: Not sure why, but I did confirm with a partner that Visual Force pages are not logged.  I did set up logging for the Site Guest user and never did see a log entry.  The way that I was able to trouble shoot the issue was to print_r in the php to return the response from the VF page controller.  There was a JSON error that was causing the PHP payload to not be delivered